# How to refer to previously matched items in a grammar?

Tags: grammar, raku

I am trying to parse a BibTeX author field, and split it into its separate authors. This will help me rewriting the initials of each author. Here is a minimal example:

```
use v6;

my $str = '{Rockhold, Mark L and Yarwood, RR and Selker, John S}';

grammar BibTexAuthor {
    token TOP {
        <all-text> 
    }
    token all-text {
        '{' <authors> '}' 
    }
    token authors { 
        [<author> [' and ' || <?before '}'>]]+
    }
    token author {
        [<-[\s}]> || [' ' <!before 'and '>]]+
    }
}

class BibTexAuthor-actions {
    method TOP($/) {
        say $/;
        print "First author = ";
        say $<author>.made[0];
        make $/.Str;
    }
    method all-text($/) {
        make $/.Str;
    }
    method authors($/) {
        make $/.Str;
    }
    method author($/) {
        make $/.Str;
    }
}
my $res = BibTexAuthor.parse( $str, actions => BibTexAuthor-actions.new).made;
```

**Output**:

```
｢{Rockhold, Mark L and Yarwood, RR and Selker, John S}｣
 all-text => ｢{Rockhold, Mark L and Yarwood, RR and Selker, John S}｣
  authors => ｢Rockhold, Mark L and Yarwood, RR and Selker, John S｣
   author => ｢Rockhold, Mark L｣
   author => ｢Yarwood, RR｣
   author => ｢Selker, John S｣
First author = Nil
```

Why am I not able to extract the first author in the `TOP` method?

Comment: `method authors($/) { make @<author>.map(*.made) }`

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks for the suggestion, but I cannot make that work. If I replace my `method authors` with your suggestion, I still get `Nil` output for first author.

Comment: $<all-text><authors><author>[0];

Comment: @Holli Thanks, that seems to work!

Comment: moritz++ answer below is better than mine. I don't mind if you re-assign the accepted answer. (if that's possible on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why am I not able to extract the first author in the `TOP` method?

Because you are not really extracting any data in the action methods. All you do is attach the string of the match to `$/.made`, which is not actually the data you want in the end.

If you want to have separate authors in the end, you should `make` an array of authors in the `authors` action method. For example:

```
use v6;

my $str = '{Rockhold, Mark L and Yarwood, RR and Selker, John S}';

grammar BibTexAuthor {
    token TOP {
        <all-text> 
    }
    token all-text {
        '{' <authors> '}' 
    }
    token authors { 
        [<author> [' and ' || <?before '}'>]]+
    }
    token author {
        [<-[\s}]> || [' ' <!before 'and '>]]+
    }
}

class BibTexAuthor-actions {
    method TOP($/) {
        make { authors => $<all-text>.made };
    }
    method all-text($/) {
        make $/<authors>.made;
    }
    method authors($/) {
        make $/<author>».made;
    }
    method author($/) {
        make $/.Str;
    }
}
my $res = BibTexAuthor.parse( $str, actions => BibTexAuthor-actions.new).made;

say $res.perl;
```

prints

```
${:authors($["Rockhold, Mark L", "Yarwood, RR", "Selker, John S"])}
```

so now the `.made` of the top-level match is a hash, where the `authors` key holds an array. If you want to access the first author, you can now say

```
say $res<authors>[0];
```

to get `Rockhold, Mark L`

Answer (score 4):

```
$<all-text><authors><author>[0];
```

Note, that I have no idea how grammars work until now. I'm learning the language as you do.

But just by looking at the datastrucure it's easy to realize it's a tree and where in that tree the value you are looking for is.

You can output any datastructure by saying

```
dd $someStructure;
say $someStructure.perl;
```

and if you find that unreadable, you can try one of the [Dumper Modules](https://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=dump)